# Assaulting a city by contaminating the rain with corrosive materials

Tags: warfare, engineering

In my world, Empires A and B are at war with each other. A is a ground based civilization, whereas B is situated on a huge plateau situated at an height of 7000m. B has Sherpa-like people who are acclimated to these altitudes, and A's soldiers suffer altitude sickness really quickly (~3000m). And also, the plateau is very steep, making climbing impossible. So far, no side has the upper hand, and are at a stalemate. That is when an imperial scientist comes up with a plan.

Sulfur is obtained from a nearby dormant volcano, and mixed with saltpeter in large barrel. These barrels are about 6ft tall, 15 inches wide, and contain 1 metric tonne each of the mixture. These are lifted by methane balloons obtained from scrubbing biogas with water.

The aim here is to get the barrels to get into a rain/thunderstorm cloud. When these barrels fly into the cloud, they get struck by lightning and burst open, creating a lot of sulfur compounds, which react with the water in the clouds to form sulfuric acid, which comes down with the rain. Theoretically, the rain should be acidic enough to dissolve human skin and armour.

**How many of these barrels would be required to make the rain so acidic that they can dissolve humans and armour?**

Technology level= Imperial China- Late Qing Dynasty

Comment: You might be able to do slow structural damage to buildings over years, but even today I don't think we could make rain that was equal to 6 molar sulfuric acid, even with giant cargo planes. The sulfur needs to solubilize, lightning wouldn't be reliable to open the barrels, and the volumes involved would bankrupt the civilization. Easier to use the sulfur to make gunpowder and dig a tunnel under the enemy.  Build rockets that drop bombs on the enemy. Dig a thousand tunnels and move your troops up through these. Acclimate your invader army.

Comment: A normal regular ordinary 16th to early 19th battle involved burning more than a tonne of sulfur and saltpeter. And at ground level, not up in the clouds. Nobody ever got dissolved. As far as the soldiers of the time were aware, the only inconvenient of burning large amounts of sulfur and saltpeter in battle was that the smoke obscured the vision. (And if the plateau is really impossible to access from the plains, then (a) Empire Bee is effectively in an impregnable position, and (b) any attempt of Empire Bee to invade Empire Ay is a net loss of soldiers, because they can never return home.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Impossible**

Acid strong enough to melt both armor and the human body is strong enough to dissolve stone, depending on what type of stone it is. It'll dissolve (or burn) wood.

1. The technology of the period was incapable of developing an acid that strong in significant quantities (compared to your goals).

Next, rain may be a whomping cool way to solve your political problems, but there are few delivery methods less efficient than a rainstorm. The vast majority of your acid will fall on things that don't require its attention for its intended purpose. In other words, destroying a dry patch of dirt a half mile away from the city was a waste of acid.

2. A rainstorm would require 10X, 100X, 1000's of X more acid than pumping it through hoses onto or over the city walls.
3. You'll destroy, at a guess for a very long time, the value of every square inch of ground the acid falls on. Including the aerobic and anaerobic bacteria that make soil useful for growing things.

On top of all this, you can't get the acid high enough with enough quantity to even begin to look like rain.

4. Acid of that strength must be transported in sealed glass containers. The weight of the containers is likely equal to the weight of the acid. It must then be distributed through glass atomizers and nozzles. And you hope like crazy the wind doesn't blow the distributed acid anywhere near stuff you want to keep.